# unable to use tcpreplay in cygwin because I can't find the interface name similar to eth0 in linux

Tags: tcpreplay

I want to use tcpreplay in cygwin to replay recorded pcap file, but it turns out very difficult, after battling with issues in building tcpreplay in cygwin environment, now i need to overcome the last hurdle.

I use this command:

tcpreplay --intf1="interface name" recorded.pcap

I tried many possible "interface name" such as Ethernet 2, "Ethernet 2", Ethernet\ 2, "\Device\NPF_{4F9C1634-3817-41FF-96A5-5818BEDA9418}", "Ethernet adapter Ethernet 2" etc, but none is working, always with "..Invalid interface name/alias.." error. and not much material online to explain how to get the interface name in Windows/cygwin similar to eth0 in Linux.

anyone has idea?

Answer (score 0):

I can answer that myself now.
Use wireshark -> Manage Interfaces, it will show the Friendly Name, which is the interface name the tcpreplay needs. also need to run tcpreplay as superuser, so need to run cygwin.bat (32bit version) as administrator